# Optimal OOP security for PubSub - Should mutual consent be required?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, object-oriented, object-oriented-design, typescript

I am implementing the Publish-Subscribe pattern.

I have class `Broker` and interfaces `IPublisher`, `ISubscriber`.

```js
interface IPublisher {
    broker: Broker;
    publish(channel: Channel, data: object): void;
}

interface ISubscriber {
    notify(channel: Channel, data: object): void;
}

class Broker {
    channels: Map<Channel, Set<ISubscriber>>

    constructor() {
        this.channels = new Map();
    }

    subscribe(channel: Channel, subscriber: ISubscriber) {
        if (!this.channels.has(channel)) {
            this.channels.set(channel, new Set());
        }
        this.channels.get(channel).add(subscriber);
    }
    unsubscribe(channel: Channel, subscriber: ISubscriber) {
        if (!this.channels.has(channel)) {
            return;
        }
        this.channels.get(channel).delete(subscriber);
    }
    broadcast(channel: Channel, data: object) {
        if (!this.channels.has(channel)) {
            return;
        }
        this.channels.get(channel).forEach(subscriber => subscriber.notify(channel, data));
    }
}
```

I am wondering about security concerns. This design currently technically allows for publishers to publish to any channel in any Broker that they have a reference to without that Broker's authorization, and for the Broker to subscribe any subscriber to itself and notify them of any channel without that subscriber's permission.

is this a problem? I've considered adding a `register(channel: Channel, publisher: IPublisher)` method to `Broker` and a `subscribe(broker: Broker, channel: Channel)` method to `ISubscriber`, splitting `Broker.channels` into two independent maps `.subscribers`, `publishers`, with an error thrown if the Broker attempts to notify a subscriber that has not subscribed to it or if the publisher attempts to publish to a channel that has not been registered with the Broker. This will require changing `ISubscriber.notify()` and `IPublisher.publish()` to pass themselves to the Broker as well.

```js
interface IPublisher {
    broker: Broker;
    publish(self: IPubllisher, channel: Channel, data: object): void;
}

interface ISubscriber {
    subscribe(broker: Broker, channel: Channel): void;
    notify(broker: Broker, channel: Channel, data: object): void;
}

class Broker {
    subscribers: Map<Channel, Set<ISubscriber>>
    publishers: Map<Channel, Set<IPublisher>>

    constructor() {
        this.subscribers = new Map();
        this.publishers = new Map();
    }
    register(channel: Channel, publisher: IPublisher) {
        if (!this.publishers.has(channel)) {
            this.publishers.set(channel, new Set());
        }
        this.publishers.get(channel).add(publisher);
    }
    subscribe(channel: Channel, subscriber: ISubscriber) {
        if (!this.subscribers.has(channel)) {
            this.subscribers.set(channel, new Set());
        }
        this.subscribers.get(channel).add(subscriber);
    }
    unsubscribe(channel: Channel, subscriber: ISubscriber) {
        if (!this.subscribers.has(channel)) {
            return;
        }
        this.subscribers.get(channel).delete(subscriber);
    }
    broadcast(publisher: IPublisher, channel: Channel, data: object) {
        if (!this.publishers.has(channel)) {
            return;
        }
        if (!this.publishers.get(channel).has(publisher)) {
            throw new Error("Publisher not registered for channel");
        }
        this.subscribers.get(channel).forEach(subscriber => subscriber.notify(this, channel, data));
    }
}
```

Is this worth it? Are there better approaches? Are there any other security concerns I should be aware of? Should I restrict access at the channel level as well, or allow any authorized entity to access any channel?

Answer (score 4):

You should mainly handle security at the perimeter, not between entities of your code. The scheme you propose would add complexity without actually protecting against external attackers. It has a slight chance of catching some coding errors, but protecting against such errors should only be done where they would result in execution of malicious code with resulting privilege escalation.